# Quais as diferenças entre MyISAM e InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, innodb

Quais as principais diferenças entre as *engines* `MyISAM` e `InnoDB` e qual a situação mais apropriada para o uso de cada?

Sei que `MyISAM` não suporta `FOREIGN KEY` mas suporta `FULLTEXT`, enquanto no `InnoDB` é o contrário, pelo menos até a versão 5.5 do MySQL.

Por que um SGBDR (RDBMS) tem como padrão uma *engine* que não oferece meios para relacionar as tabelas?

Comment: O `Full-text search` (FTS) foi implementando no innoDB a partir da versão 5.6.4 do MySql, no entanto existem algumas restrições: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Default

Este é o *default* porque é ele que dá mais performance (mas logo em versão seguinte deixou de ser, e é curioso porque pra maioria dos cenários que as pessoas que menos se preocupam e usam o MySQL o InnoDB não é o mais adequado). O MyISAM é mais simples, mas principalmente porque é ele que as pessoas mais buscam quando usam o MySQL, é o que fez a fama do MySQL. Ele é preferido porque em grande parte das aplicações simples onde ele é usado, relacionamento de tabelas não é tão importante. Ou até é, mas pode muito bem ser feito pela aplicação. Há quem goste ou precise que este controle seja feito no banco de dados, mas não é o caso de todo mundo, de todo projeto.

## Quando usar

Se você precisa de performance e simplicidade vai optar pelo MyISAM. Se precisa dos controles mais apurados, opte pelo InnoDB. Em geral não tem porque optar por ele se você não precisa, e não sabe usar os recursos dele. E grande parte dos projetos pequenos não precisam destes recursos. Alguns mais "maldosos" vão dizer que se você precisa do InnoDB, então é melhor optar por outro banco de dados mais completo, que faz mais por você. Não deixa de ser verdade que o InnoDB deixa um pouco a desejar para alguns outros SGDBs. Alguns dizem até que o MySQL só é uma escolha válida se usar o MyISAM. É claro que outros discordam.

Em geral quando você tem muita leitura e pouca escrita, o MyISAM costuma se sair melhor. O InnoDB pode ter vantagens se a quantidade de escrita verdadeiramente concorrente é muito grande. O que é mais raro.

O InnoDB não tem como ser mais rápido pelo simples fato dele fazer mais coisas que o MyISAM. A não ser que o MyISAM fosse muito mal implementado, ele tem que ser mais rápido. Ele não tem tanta escalabilidade que é diferente de não ter performance. As pessoas às vezes confundem essas coisas. Um banco de dados puramente *flat file* seria o mais rápido de todos pelo menos para certas operações.

#### Relacionamento

Você consegue relacionar tabelas com MyISAM. Você só não vai fazer isto na definição do modelo. Não existe uma forma de obrigar o relacionamento acontecer de forma automática, mas faz isto nas suas *queries* normalmente, sem perder nada. Quando a lógica costuma estar mais na aplicação que no banco de dados é comum preferir não forçar o relacionamento e deixar o `JOIN` na *query* se encarregar disto. Tudo tem vantagens e desvantagens mas isto é outro assunto.

## *Tradeoffs*

Existem sistemas de bancos de dados ainda mais simples e provavelmente mais rápidos. Para cada problema, uma solução. Tudo são escolhas. Não dá para fazer mágica e ter tudo. Embora o MariaDB tentou conciliar um pouco mais essas coisas com o *engine* [Aria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_%28storage_engine%29) (dá para usar com MySQL).

## Comparativos

| Feature | MyISAM | InnoDB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ACID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101) | Não | Sim |
| Configuração do comportamento ACID | Não | Sim |
| Proteção quando quebra | Não | Sim * |
| Chave estrangeira automática | Não | Sim |
| [MVCC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192938/101) | Não | Sim |
| Tipo Geoespacial | Sim | Sim |
| Indexação Geoespacial | Sim | Sim |
| Indexação Full-Text | Sim | Sim [4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) |
| Cache de dados | Não | Sim |
| Capacidade total do banco | 256TB | 64TB |
| Ocupação de espaço em disco | Baixa | Alta |
| Ocupação de espaço em memória | Baixa | Alta |
| Travamento | Tabela | Registro |
| Capacidade de leitura concorrente ** | Alta | Regular |
| Capacidade de escrita concorrente ** | Baixa | Alta |
| Backup facilitado * | Não | Sim |
| COUNT(8) rápido *** | Sim | Não |
| Compressão de dados | Leitura | Leitura/Gravação |

`*` Há controvérsias (já vi muitos relatos que dá problemas)
`**` Depende muito da carga real
`***` Muitos consideram que isto é irrelevante

Tem uma [comparação na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: InnoDB mudou muito, algumas coisas que falam sobre performance são de 2011 ou antes... As dicas são boas porém estão meio "", é apenas a minha opinião.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você consegue contar até 10 mais rápido que contar até 5? É isto que você está dizendo. O MyISAM é e sempre será mais rápido enquanto ele não tiver transações e outras formas de garantias. Só quantidade de escrita menor que ele tem que fazer já dá uma diferença enorme. Tem várias coisas que o InnoDB pode evoluir quanto quiser que não vai ficar mais rápido. A não ser que ele corte funcionalidades. Quando você faz menos, você faz mais rápido a não ser que você seja muito ineficiente, muito mesmo. O que não é o caso de nenhum *engine* mesmo de outros DBs.

Comment: Eu não disse em nenhum momento que ele superou o myisam, o que eu disse é que muitos testes usados hojes para mostrar o CUSTO-BENEFÍCIO estão DESATUALIZADOS.

Comment: Boa resposta. Sempre vejo as pessoas criticando o `MYISAM`. É bom ver opinião de pessoas que balanceiam os dois lados

Answer (score 16):

Encontrei uma explicação muito bem detalhada e gostaria de compartilhar, talvez possa te ajudar.

**Observações gerais**

> InnoDB funciona mais rápido que MyISAM quando há modificações constantes nos dados, uma vez que este tipo de armazenagem usa a proteção por registros (row locking) e não a proteção por tabelas (table locking) como o faz o MyISAM. Contudo, em várias situações, InnoDB é mais lento que MyISAM, devido ao fato de que InnoDB funciona com transações. A armazenagem padrão do MySQL é MyISAM. Outro ponto interessante são as restrições de chaves estrangeiras (foreign key constraints) e transações. Estes recursos estão disponíveis apenas no InnoDB. 
>   MyISAM é apropriado para tabelas cujos dados não mudam com frequência. Um exemplo disso é uma tabela de cidades e estados. Como geralmente este tipo de tabela é usado apenas como consultas, não há a necessidade do uso de InnoDB.

**MyISAM**

> Foi implementado a partir do código da tabela ISAM., introduzindo diversas melhorias como:
>
> > Os arquivos de tabela são transportáveis entre diferentes sistemas operacionais;
> >     Campos BLOB  e TEXT  podem ser indexados;
> >
> > Os Arquivos índices e de dados podem ser armazenados em dispositivos diferentes (aumento de performance);
> >
> > Algoritmos de distribuição de dados e gerenciamento de índices melhorados;

**InnoDB**

> > Rodam sob um engine, desenvolvido pelo Innobase( www.innodb.com), que acrescenta ao MySQL o suporte a TRANSAÇÕES e a CONSTRAINTS de chave estrangeira.
> >
> > Para obter o máximo de performance com tabelas InnoDB é necessário configurar o arquivo my.conf(ou my.ini no Windows) de acordo com as características de hardware do servidor onde o MySQL está rodando. Os Detalhes dessa configuração podem ser obtidos no manual do InnoDB.

Para maiores detalhes [clique aqui](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/789/mysql_-_diferenca_entre_innodb_e_myisam)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Achei sua resposta mais curta e mais direta, e sem achismo e controvérsias, no demais que cada um faça seus testes e experimente, fazer benchmark em BD é muito subjetivo

Comment: @SneepSNinjA mostre os achismos na minha resposta.

Comment: @bigown você já os citou *Há controvérsias (já vi muitos relatos que dá problemas) algumas palavras deixam o leitor a merce de muita subjetividade exemplo "...Não deixa de ser verdade..", "..Alguns dizem..", "..outros discordam..", "..Tudo tem vantagens e desvantagens.."

Comment: @bigown a resposta esta certa, você respondeu com a sua experiência e vivencia, sei que é difícil responder sem fazer algum tipo de comparação de performance, mas a verdade esta nas duas respostas, são coisas diferentes que tem bom desempenho em ambientes diferentes tais quais foram respondidas em ambas as respostas

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Porque o assunto é subjetivo e você mesmo disse. Tentar tornar algo subjetivo como se fosse objetivo é enganar o leitor. É fazer afirmações falsas. As coisas não são preto no branco. Eu dei uma resposta honesta mostrando que não dá para dizer qual é melhor. Outras partes mais objetivas não precisaram destas ressalvas. Bom, eu considero esta resposta bastante limitada, não tem nada errado nela (apesar que uma frase pode ser interpretada erroneamente por quem não entende do assunto), mas ela reduz a alguns aspectos. Pode parecer que são só estas diferenças.

Comment: Concordo @bigown para quem não entende do assunto alguns comentários podem levar a uma interpretação errada por exemplo "..InnoDB deixa a desejar para alguns outros SGDBs.." da a impressão que o InnoDB não vale nada, quando na verdade depende muito da ótica, se formos olhar pelo Custo x performance isso seria uma afirmação muito injusta.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Agora entendi, você gosta do InnoDB e não gostou do que eu disse. Eu poderia ser mais completo e mostrar os inúmeros problemas que ele tem, comparando com outras soluções. Mas você prefere respostas curtas que não informam nada, então vou deixar como está.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31364/discussion-between-sneeps-ninja-and-bigown).