# O que é a técnica Multi-Version Concurrency Control no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, lock

O que é Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) no PostgreSQL e como é seu funcionamento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É uma técnica onde nada é escrito por cima. Toda mudança nos dados é criada uma nova instância dele em outro local e vai atualizando as referências para o novo local. Desta forma não precisa de travamento quando está escrevendo, todas leituras podem acessar o dado antigo sem problemas porque é garantido que ele não está sendo alterado, outras escritas não afetam o que esta transação está fazendo.

Com o MVCC se obtém o [**isolamento** e facilita a **consistência** e **atomicidade**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101) do [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) e em alguns casos pode facilitar a **durabilidade**. É um mecanismo simples e eficiente se bem implementado. Cada transação é totalmente independente e livre de efeitos colaterais.

Obviamente que precisa de alguma forma de coletor de lixo para reaproveitar as páginas de dados e índices que não estão mais sendo usadas por alguma transação.

Em outras palavras, todo objeto do banco de dados é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), é como a *string* de muitas linguagens, você pode criar uma nova, mas não pode mexer na existente, a nova pode ser referenciada pelo mesmo local de antes parecendo que ela é a mesma *string*.

A técnica não elimina toda necessidade de gerenciamento. Se duas transações estiverem ocorrendo simultaneamente existe caso em que se deseja apenas o dado antigo, mas existe situação em que o dado já modificado na outra transação precisa seja visto, por isso tem configuração que permite o acesso ao novo dado.

Para dar mais detalhes precisaria explicar todo funcionamento do banco de dados, a separação em páginas, árvore binária, etc., o que não caberia aqui.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

[Apresentação do mantenedor](http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/internalpics.pdf).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).