# Faz diferença deletar e criar novas linhas ou fazer update nas antigas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, sql-update, delete

Não levando em conta a dificuldade técnica de fazer uma coisa ou outra, mas sim a consistência do banco, a velocidade das posteriores operações e o profissionalismo.

Se tenho uma tabela em banco de dados (PostgreSQL), com uma `PRIMARY KEY` auto-incrementada e preciso atualizar essa tabela, qual a diferença entre os casos?

1 - Fazer `UPDATE` das linha que já existem e eventualmente criar e deletar linhas quando estritamente necessário.

2 - Deletar todas as linhas referentes a um cadastro (a estrutura é relacional e nesta tabela são armazenadas algumas linhas referentes a um único cadastro) e criar linhas novas com as novas informações.

Obs.: Sei fazer das duas formas, não é isso que quero saber. O que quero saber está no primeiro parágrafo do texto.

Comment: olha, não sei no detalhe como o `postgresql` trabalha, mas no `sql-server`, deletar e incluir é mais rápido, porém, o arquivo de LOG fica cheio pois as linhas excluídas vão parar lá, excessão se usar o `truncate table`, mas ambas as soluções requerem receriar todos os índices, e isso em ambos os bancos, isso é um ponto de atenção, tanto de performance como de processamento, especialmente **IO**

Comment: Pelo visto sua chave artificial não serve para nada já que, como você diz, manter o mesmo valor (no caso do UPDATE) ou modificá-lo (no caso do TRUNCATE/INSERT) não trás nenhuma consequência para seus dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claro que faz diferença, uma coisa é uma coisa, outra coisa é outra coisa.

Saiba que do ponto de vista interno o PostgreSQL já cria uma nova linha e cria outra sempre que for fazer um `UPDATE`, porque ele trabalha com uma técnica chamada [MVCC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192938/101) (Multi Version Concurrency Control), o que é simples para manter o isolamento e consistência nas transações. Então a performance é para ser essencialmente a mesma. Claro, pode ter uns pequenos detalhes que podem interferir um pouco, mas como são detalhes de implementação eu não contaria muito isso.

Se tudo for feito em uma transação, semanticamente é para ser a mesma coisa se estiver em modo serializado. Se não estiver em transação ou estiver em outro modo pode ter uma chance maior de indevido acesso a dados que ainda não estão completos se fizer o `DELETE` e `INSERT`.

Se for apagar e criar a chave primária será a mesma ou nova? Isso é importante porque tem uma semântica diferente. Se for manter a mesma, qual a vantagem para seu problema de apagar e criar outra linha?

Se tanto faz para seu problema eu iria de `UPDATE`. Mas seu problema pode exigir criar uma linha nova e apagar. Se importa pouco, faz o simples.

Se vai fazer algo diferente deveria justificar a escolha, você consegue justificar o apagamento e criação? Se for muito importante decidir por um ou outro aí é melhor que a decisão seja sustentada por um estudo bastante aprofundado e melhor análise do caso concreto.

Uma coisa que eu vejo o pessoal errar muito é apagar ou alterar um dado quando o problema pede para não fazer isto. Há situações que você nunca deveria ter perda de dados, então só deveria existir `INSERT` na(s) tabela(s). Só estou dizendo isso como curiosidade, não parece ser o caso (espero).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).