# O que é o vacuum?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, otimização

O que significar o vacuuming em um banco de dados? O que acontece quando chamamos o comando `VACUUM`. E por que alguns SGDBs não precisam dele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O termo é usado em alusão ao aspirador de pó, porque é isso que ele faz, ele aspira o pó, ou seja, objetos que não são mais necessários na estrutura do banco de dados. Ele é uma espécie de *garbage collector*, mas um pouco diferente. Podemos dizer que ele é um desfragmentador também, porque esse processo tende a fazer o acesso ser mais rápido já que as [árvores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/582172/101) costumam ficar menores e mais bem balanceadas.

Ele vai retirando fisicamente tudo o que pode ser retirado. O mais comum é sumir com as linhas que foram `DELETE`adas com comando SQL. Mas também pode tirar definitivamente [páginas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/582172/101) que foram largadas pelo processo de atualização de dados ou algum uso temporário.

Quando você apaga uma linha ela não é apagada de fato do arquivo, ela apenas não é mais considerada até ela ser "aspirada".

Especialmente em bancos de dados que usam [MVCC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192938/101) é comum as páginas que não são mais atuais serem largadas para trás e em algum momento você precisa liberar isso.

Tem arquiteturas que não usam MVCC (gravam tudo em cima) ou já contam com algum mecanismo de reaproveitamento dessas páginas logo a seguir, então o GC do DB é mais determinístico e mais eficiente, embora possa custar um pouco mais o processamento real. Um GC que faz sob demanda em momento sem muito processamento real pode ser melhor.

Tem muito caso que um espaço é reservado para ter algum ganho de performance, mas depois não é usado, e precisa ser removido em algum momento.

Mutas vezes é feito assim porque é complicado reduzir o tamanho do arquivo. Fazer isso costuma custar caro na maioria das *file systems*.

Tem caso que ele faz, mas não exige que você dê um comando, ele sabe quando fazer. O problema é que ele pode não saber quando não fazer, e pode atrapalhar o processamento real.

Em alguns casos o que ele faz é só montar um *free list* para reaproveitar as páginas, o que alguns já fazem na hora, como já falei antes. Tem casos que reorganiza as páginas, até mesmo pode copiar tudo para uma nova estrutura. A maneira exata depende da qualidade e capacidade de concorrência que o DB quer dar.

Eu usava um banco de dados que o comando chamava `PACK` e muita gente o chamava logo depois de dar `DELETE`, era uma tragédia, dupla, o resultado e ver alguém fazendo isso. A pessoa não se conformava que não apagava de fato, só não considerava mais na *queries*. Mas foi feito assim porque é melhor limpar em lotes e não imediatamente depois. A pessoa fazia por ingenuidade. Hoje a pessoa pode ficar tão ingênua que ela nem sabe que o `DELETE` não deleta de fato.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).