# O que é ACID em banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, acid

Não estou falando de [indicador de implementação de web](http://www.acidtests.org/).

Além da sigla, por que ele é importante?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [**A**tomicidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))

  É algo indivisível. Ou tudo o que está em uma transação deve ser realizado com sucesso, ou nada deve ser realizado. Pelo menos nada deva ser considerado como realizado. Sem a atomicidade fica difícil se não impossível manter as outras características, por isso a transação é importante.
- [**C**onsistência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems))

  O banco de dados deve ter uma transação terminada em estado consistente, ou seja, deve respeitar todas as regras impostas no banco de dados para todos os envolvidos na transação.
- [**I**solamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))

  Uma transação não pode interferir em outra enquanto está em atividade. Só após sua conclusão é que o seu resultado ficará disponível para outras transações.
- [**D**urabilidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(database_systems))

  Ao final da transação o resultado deve permanecer no banco de dado, aconteça o que acontecer.

## Motivação

Sem essas características o banco de dados não é confiável. Uma operação pode terminar pela metade, ou pode estar em um estado que causará problemas, ou manipulará dados que ainda não se sabe se serão úteis ou finais ou ainda pode perder o que foi feito.

Alguns bancos de dados se dizem ACID quando na verdade são apenas quase ACID :) Eles são ACID, *pero no mucho*, tem alguns casos que eles não garantem isso, ou seja eles dizem que estão mais ou menos grávidos :)

O conceito é implementado para evitar [condições de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) e problemas semelhantes. No *link* tem um exemplo de conta bancária que é o clássico problema.

- Se você precisa atualizar o saldo de uma conta precisa garantir que tudo o que é feito para mudar o saldo deve ser realizado até o fim, não pode mudar em uma tabela e não mudar em outra, não pode debitar em uma conta e deixar de debitar em outra (atomicidade).
- No final da transação não pode deixar o saldo com um valor que foi determinado que não seja permitido, por exemplo: saldo normal mais limite ser negativo,  ou o saldo não ter uma operação vinculada a ele (consistência).
- Não pode deixar outras transações verem o crédito até que se conclua, já que a transação pode não dar certo ou pode ser que durante ela também tenha outros créditos ou débitos que afetarão o resultado final (isolamento).
- Não pode deixar de manter o novo valor do saldo e tudo o que foi realizado para se chegar nele (durabilidade).

Normalmente isto é obtido por um sistema de *journaling*, *write ahead log* ou alguma forma semelhante. É importante que as operações da transação sejam feitas
fora do acesso normal do banco de dados e só entre no seu final. As técnicas mais utilizadas são [*two phase locking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking), [*multi version concurrency control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) e [*snapshot isolation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation).

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Os bancos de dados chamados de NoSQL não costumam ser ACID (alguns até são, alguns são parcialmente, ou seja, não são). Os que são não oferecem todas aquelas vantagens que dizem que o NoSQL tem, não existe milagre. Ou eles não são confiáveis. Claro que problemas que o desempenho geral e a distribuição são mais importantes que a confiabilidade da informação então ele é útil. Assim como tem problemas assim, bancos de dados ACID podem ter melhor desempenho em certos cenários.

Se não souber o que está fazendo o NoSQL pode ser trágico e muito mais lento. NoSQL opta pelo [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) que podemos chamar de oposto do ACID, ainda que não seja bem assim.

Veja sobre o [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). Ele mostra que não existe milagre. Não acredite em falsos profetas que prometem que vão resolver todos os problemas e quebrar o CAP theorem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).