# Como o Oracle age após a execução de um script PHP sem commit?

Tags: php, oracle, commit

Se eu executar uma série de comandos SQL com banco de dados Oracle, biblioteca OCI, sem executar o *commit* e definindo que não irá ser feito *commit* automático.

O que o Oracle fará ao final da execução do script PHP? Um rollback ou um commit?

Comment: Isso depende da configuração do banco.

Comment: @rray essa pergunta é meio ampla, né?

Comment: Por que não testa você mesmo?

Comment: Em parte essa pergunta responde => [O que é ACID em banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/91) que seria o conceito de atomicidade.

Comment: Pessoal, melhorei a pergunta e tentei deixar mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

PHP não faz nada porque é uma linguagem de programação, a questão é se a biblioteca faz, mas qual está usando? A padrão, na configuração padrão do DB? Não faz automático. Tem que chamar o [`oci_commit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-commit.php). Usando [`OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) ele será executado no fim da execução da *query* se estiver tudo ok.

Comment: Então, estou usando a OCI mesmo mas sem commit automático. Gostaria de saber como o Oracle irá agir nesse caso.