# Estrutura de tabelas para calculo de transações financeiras no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, estrutura-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que terá transações financeiras. Nesse sistema o usuário poderá inserir ou retirar dinheiro, poderá comprar e vender produtos, enviar dinheiro para outros usuários, e etc.

Atualmente eu tenho uma tabela de usuários que além dos dados de cadastro, contém também o saldo total de dinheiro que o usuário tem em sua carteira (`wallet`).

E outra tabela de transações, onde indica todas transações que foram feitas, dinheiro que entrou ou saiu da conta (`in_or_out`), qual referência da transação (`transaction_ref`) e valor (`value`) que foi transferido.

Segue abaixo a estrutura atual:

[image: relacionamento das tabelas]

Meu medo é que por algum erro na transação o valor não seja somado na tabela do usuário. Ou que o usuário efetue um pagamento e o valor não seja descontado da tabela. Porque estarei sempre levando em consideração o valor do *wallet* do usuário como o dinheiro que ele tem em conta.

Então se ele fizer uma compra, por exemplo de R$ 1.000,00, e esse valor não for descontado da conta dele, ele ainda terá o mesmo valor para gastar, o que pode dar um prejuízo depois para a empresa ter que pagar o prejuízo do valor adicional gasto, já que com 1 milhão de usuários, ficaria difícil saber de qual usuário que deu o problema.

Daí eu pensei: em vez de fazer um total da carteira na tabela do usuário, que eu fizesse sempre uma consulta somando as transações. Aí nesse caso fico pensando, se eu tiver 1 milhão de usuários, e 1 bilhão de transações, ficaria muito pesado pra se somar o tempo todo, podendo trazer muita lentidão nas consultas do sistema.

Alguém que tenha alguma experiência com cálculos, ou sistemas parecidos, poderia me orientar uma lógica melhor para estruturar essas tabelas?

Eu não preciso que me passem os códigos de consulta e soma etc. Só preciso entender uma forma melhor de estrutura de quem tem mais experiência no assunto.

Lembrando que a estrutura atual ainda pode ser modificada de qualquer forma necessária.

Comment: comece lendo https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for feito o código certo, com transação do SGDB ligada (em MyISAM não tem transação), não tem porque ter esse medo, o banco de dados está aí para dar garantia que todas tabelas serão atualizadas ou nenhuma será (atomicidade do [ACID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101)), mantendo a consistência. Você não está lidando com NoSQL que não dá essa garantia.

Confie no banco de dados, não confie no seu código.

Se ainda preferir manter o saldo pegando das transações financeiras, e tudo estiver configurado corretamente, com índices adequados, uma consulta que pega os valores das transações para encontrar o saldo certamente será mais lenta, mas pode não ser tanto quanto imagina e poderia ser uma solução. Eu acho que a chance de cometer algum erro fazendo assim é maior.

Não existem respostas únicas e definitivas que resolvam todos os problemas, cada caso tem uma forma de resolver que se adéqua mais.

Comment: É que esse sistema também será usado em aplicativos. Com muitos usuários simultâneos. Fico com receio de por exemplo o usuário fazer uma compra e essa compra for registrada na tabela de transações, mas se der uma pequena queda no sistema no momento e não der tempo de alterar o valor da carteira na tabela do usuário. 

As vezes um erro de meio segundo no sistema de hospedagem pode causar um grande prejuízo. Talvez eu nunca tenha esse tipo de problema, mas como é a primeira vez que vou fazer algo financeiro, é sempre bom perguntar pros mais experientes no assunto kkk Obrigado por responder.