# Como substituir o COUNT(*) no innoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Migrei dados de um banco *MyISAM* para *InnoDB* e algumas `VIEW` ficaram extremamente lentas(em média 15x mais lenta), depois de muita pesquisa encontrei [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41678/77723) do @maniero e nela ele faz uma comparação entre as duas engines.

Na resposta dele notei que o InnoDB é lento com cláusula `COUNT(*)` foi então que removi o `COUNT(*)` do `SELECT` dentro da `VIEW` e aqui está o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

310x mais rápido.

A query que estou executando é essa(Diminui para ficar mais legível):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        `a`.`ASSINATURAS_ID` AS `ASSINATURAS_ID`,
        `pd`.`PEDIDOS_DETALHES_Descricao_Produto` AS `PEDIDOS_DETALHES_Descricao_Produto`,
        `pd`.`FK_PRODUTO` AS `FK_PRODUTO`,
        (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                `licencas`
            WHERE
                (`licencas`.`FK_PEDIDO` = `p`.`PEDIDOS_ID`)) AS `TotalDownloadSubscriptionCount`,
    FROM
        ((`n_assinaturas` `a`
        JOIN `pedidos` `p` ON ((`p`.`PEDIDOS_ID` = `a`.`FK_PEDIDO`)))
        JOIN `planos_conta` `pc` ON ((`pc`.`ID_PLANOS_Conta` = `p`.`FK_PLANOS_Conta`)))
```

Existe uma opção ao `COUNT(*)` no *InnoDB* ?

Comment: Meu pêsames, saiu de algo bom pra algo questionável.

Comment: tenta `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM nome_da_tabela limit 1;` depois
`SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

Comment: @Maniero infelizmente fui "forçado" pela hospedagem compartilhada

Comment: @HebertLima vou testar

Comment: @HebertLima como eu aplicaria isso numa subquery?

Comment: vou explicar na resposta

Comment: @HebertLima vou atualizar a pergunta com a query que eu estava fazendo ok?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti blz

Comment: @HebertLima pronto, diminui ela para ficar mais legivel, de qualquer forma se você puder me explicar como seria na minha subquery vai ajudar muito , enquanto isso vou pesquisando mais sobre essas clausulas

Answer (score 0):

**SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS()**

É uma função interna do `MySQL` que calcula os registro de linha da query executada, mesmo que você defina um valor para o `limit` a função ira calcular o numero total de registro na tabela.

**FOUND_ROWS()**

É a função que armazena a quantiade de linhas que a função `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` executou.

você pode achar a explicação completa na documentação do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Para a sua query, você não ira obter ambos registros ao mesmo tempo sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       `a`.`ASSINATURAS_ID` AS `ASSINATURAS_ID`... 
        // restante da query
```

após executar a query, você precisa fazer um novo select com a função `FOUND_ROWS()`

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total;
```

uma outra opção seria você criar uma `procedure` para realizar essa contagem passando por parâmetro o nome da tabela;

Obs: meus conhecimentos sobre procedures são poucos eu tentei montar um exemplo mas não deu certo xD, mas vou por a ideia pra caso alguem queria complementar:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE numero_de_registros ( in tabela varchar(200) )
BEGIN
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tabela limit 1;
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

// para chamar seria algo
call numero_de_registros(tabela);
```